# Windows 10 to Window 11 upgrade on dual boot(windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Please share your experience regarding:
Windows 10 to Window 11 upgrade on dual boot system. Currently I have windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Grub. Anything special needs to be done? Windows is on SSD while Ubuntu Linux is on PCIE NVME SSD.

Answer (score 0):

There have been instances that Windows got rid of grub and replaced it with its own bootloader. If that happens, you will have to restore Grub from a live USB.

To prevent this hassle, you can detach the Ubuntu SSD while upgrading Windows. Later, boot from the Ubuntu's SSD (you may have to reset the default OS to Ubuntu in UEFI), and run `sudo update-grub` so that it replaces Windows 10 with Windows 11 in the GRUB.

Comment: This would work particularly well if the Ubuntu SSD has its own ESP. However, the default installation of Ubuntu using the dual boot option puts part of GRUB in the ESP it finds, the one in the Windows SSD. In that case, the Windows upgrade may delete the ESP part of the GRUB even if you remove the Ubuntu SSD.